# CSS change stroke property of <path>

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a generated svg path code, I want to override it with CSS in such a way that I dont want any stroke that generates by default. How can I override the propert of stroke and set it to none.

code:

```
<div class="container" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; z-index: 1;">
<svg height="35" version="1.1" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
</defs>
<path fill="#cecece" stroke="#808080" d="M503.7,743.8C694,647.1999999999999,636.6,326.74999999999994,348.1,334.09V205.39L120.00000000000003,400.39L348.1,606.19V474.59000000000003C589,469.09000000000003,578,677.3900000000001,503.70000000000005,743.8900000000001Z" stroke-width="40" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.05,0,0,0.05,-1.9,-5.7)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;">
</path>
</svg>
</div>
```

I tried:

css:

```
.container svg path {
   stroke: none;
}
```

it does set to none, however it also removes the lines on the graph.

before:

[image]

after adding the `stroke: none`

[image]

I dint want to lose the lines on  the graph.any idea how to fix this?
thanks!

Comment: Adding `stroke: none;` in CSS works. Maybe you need to give your path an `id` or a `class` or use `.container svg path:nth-of-type...`

Comment: these points are dynamically generated based on the chart data, I'm not sure if I can do the nth type or if so, I'm not aware how to do it. Same thing while adding a class to the path...

Comment: can you add a link to your code? Those circles may be in a different group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, not through CSS though, I added the `lineWidth:0` property to my chart inside the `plotOptions` and that did the trick. 
Thank you all for the help!

```
  plotOptions: {
                                      area: {
                                          marker: {
                                            symbol: 'circle',
                                            lineWidth: 0,
                                              enabled: true,
                                              states: {
                                                  hover: {
                                                      enabled: true,
                                                      lineWidth: 0;
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      },
                                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get rid of the border

```
.container svg path {
   stroke-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however same thing happens when I set stroke-width to 0, it makes the lines on the graph disappear, attached image above

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question a little there

Answer (score 0):

You can set:

```css
.container svg path {
   stroke: #cecece;
}
```